# set POJO's setter using java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: java

I have POJO named LogingBean contain two fields named username and password and getter setter for the same.

Is it possible to set value of out VO's field using java.lang.reflect.method API ?

Comment: Technically a POJO is distinct from a JavaBean in that it doesn't follow a convention. Do you mean a JavaBean with setters/getters or a POJO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but this is one way to invoke a setter using reflection.

```
LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
Method setUserName = loginBean.getClass().getMethod("setUserName", new Class[]{String.class});
setUserName.invoke(loginBean, "myLogin");
```

Comment: IT's work fine but for not String value its throw an exception like java.lang.NoSuchMethodException. even Integer.class or Date.class not work.

Comment: How to get value from bean's getter method using java.lang.reflect ?

Comment: Method getUserName = loginBean.getClass().getMethod("getUserName");
    String userName = (String) getUserName.invoke(loginBean);